# How to setup CHelper and configure on IntelliJ?

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea

I tried for last two days. But I always draw a blank. I have trouble in setting up the project, and adding dependencies - and creating tasks - it always shows some error or the other.

I followed instructions from [here](https://code.google.com/p/idea-chelper/wiki/MainPage)
Created a tusk and when I tried to run it, ended up with this exceptions

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.egork.chelper.codegeneration.CodeGenerationUtilities.getSimpleName(CodeGenerationUtilities.java:374)
at net.egork.chelper.codegeneration.SolutionGenerator.createMainClassTemplate(SolutionGenerator.java:432)
at net.egork.chelper.codegeneration.SolutionGenerator$3.run(SolutionGenerator.java:503)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
at net.egork.chelper.codegeneration.SolutionGenerator.createSourceFile(SolutionGenerator.java:488)
at net.egork.chelper.util.TaskUtilities.createSourceFile(TaskUtilities.java:14)
at net.egork.chelper.configurations.TaskConfiguration.getState(TaskConfiguration.java:65)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:201)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:58)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:53)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.GenericProgramRunner.execute(GenericProgramRunner.java:31)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:94)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.a(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:375)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$400(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:60)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$4.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:368)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:318)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.e(IdeEventQueue.java:748)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:577)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:384)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

So I will appreciate if there is someone who is using it currently and give me a step by step full instruction form first to last, not only setup but also how to configure properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have installed chelper and now its working properly.
I am on ***ubuntu 16.04*** and using ***intelliJ IDEA 16.2.2***

***Steps:***

Select menu item **File->Settings...**, select **Plugins** in **IDE Settings**, push **Browse repositories...** button, right click on CHelper and select **Download and Install**(dont install the beta version).  Click **Yes**, **OK**, **Apply** and **Restart**.

Right click on main toolbar, select **Customize Menus and Toolbars...**, select location where you want actions to be listed (probably end of **Main Toolbar** is good), click **Add After...**, select **Plug-ins->CHelper** and add actions you are interested in(probably all but **Task**)

After that open or create project that you want to use with plugin and click on **Edit Project Settings** from toolbar to set-up project directories.

This is the simplest project settings that works fine for me.

[image]

now for testing you can parse a contest or problem form **Parse Contest** from toolbar. parse a problem. you will find the problem(task) in you `src/code` folder and and after compiling the source will be create in `test` directory under project. and the name of the file will be `Main.java`, You can also copy source form the menu.

Browese this [wiki page](https://code.google.com/archive/p/idea-chelper/wikis), for more information.